# usb local and remote port configuration via cmd batch

Tags: powershell, batch-file, cmd, usbserial

(xpost from superuser with no answers.)

I am trying to reconfigure a known (virtual?) com port on multiple computers on a local network using a batch file.

A USB device we use is installed always as com9 and always comes in as default 9600 baud, and we have to manually reconfigure each station to 57600 baud.

I already have this batch file renaming printers, dns servers, Killing and starting tasks, copying files and a whole lot more, I've experimented with mode, but I'm either not using it properly or it can't do what I want.

I know I can use the GUI, but for the sake of speed, I want the batch to do it.

Sorry if this is a copy, but I'm seeing if anyone has an angle for me, I'm not afraid of personal research, but I'm running into dead ends with no leads.

Ask if you need any clarifications, and thanks in advance.

Powershell is okay too if I know what I need and can still stay in the cmd environment.

Comment: Please edit your question and copy/paste the code you have been trying to make work. Tell what it does and what you want it to do. Create an `MCVE` https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve Someone may be able to help.

Comment: TBH i was messing locally with Mode trying to change settings on Com9 but nothing ever seemed to line up or change on the gui side i was checking it through.      My problem is I'm lost at this point,  if i got a pointer to a specific command i might be missing, i could go grind my brain against that.   The code for that section is largely not relevant as it does not configure com ports currently, its just the for loop logic framework.

Comment: This page talks about managing devices with PowerShell. https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wincat/2012/09/06/device-management-powershell-cmdlets-sample-an-introduction/